# Is there a way to configure IE9 so that it starts in IE8 compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I'm working on a Selenium-based continuous integration server for website testing. We can only afford one Windows box at the moment, so it has to provide for our IE7, IE8, and IE9 testing. Is there any way I can automatically set up Internet Explorer 9 so that when it runs, it already starts in IE8 or IE7 Compatibility Mode, rather than needing to set that mode every single time a test is run?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting X-UA-Compatible:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

There are others as well to force compat mode or forcing full standards mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I don't want to change the website I'm working in, I want to force the browser itself to start. The point is to test a specific browser's reaction to our website, not to force all browsers that access our site into a specific emulation mode.

Comment: Would it be possible to add/change that meta tag per test execution to get the behavior desired?  I allow a view to override the application layout to force a particular mode for IE if needed within a Rails app.